# SSRS format minutes as Days:Hours:Minutes

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I have Arrival Date and Departure Dates and the difference between them in minutes. I would like to format the difference between the dates as DD:HH:mm (Days:24-hours format:minutes). For instance, the minutes 3245 should be shown as 02:02:45(2 days, 2 hours and 45 minutes => 2*1440 + 2*60 + 45).
I've tried DateDiff function, but could not get the exact formatting. Also I need to Sum up these at the end.
Please help me with the Report Expression.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take alook at this answer to a similar question. You should be able to easily modify this to  calculate days too. For the sum part of your question ,just pass SUM(Fields!myMinutesField.Value) to the function.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - I think you forgot a link.

Comment: Good spot - Thank you :) Yes I meant to include this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72212987/how-to-display-time-in-hours-overshooting-24-hours-in-ssrs

Comment: @AlanSchofield - hey, that's your answer. :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two columns. One will display the formatted expession and one hidden will contain the datediff calculations.

Your calculation column will contain the datediff expression in minutes

```
= DATEDIFF("n",Fields!date1.Value,Fields!date2.Value)
```

For the total you can normally use SUM

```
= SUM(DATEDIFF("n",Fields!date1.Value,Fields!date2.Value))
```

Your expression display textboxes should refer to the relevant report items (in my example Textbox6 is for detail and Textbox9 is for total)

```
= Cstr(ReportItems!Textbox6.value \ (24*60)) & ":" &
Format( (ReportItems!Textbox6.value Mod (24*60)) \ 60, "00" ) & ":" &
Format( (ReportItems!Textbox6.value Mod (24*60))  Mod 60,  "00" )

= Cstr(ReportItems!Textbox9.value \ (24*60)) & ":" &
Format( (ReportItems!Textbox9.value Mod (24*60)) \ 60, "00" ) & ":" &
Format( (ReportItems!Textbox9.value Mod (24*60))  Mod 60,  "00" )
```

[image]

[image]

[image]